# Map not being displayed in android Marshmallow latest update

Tags: android, google-maps, android-6.0-marshmallow, supportmapfragment

Android Version - android 6.0.1
Device - Micromax canvas A1
SDK Level -target 23 & min 14

I am Working on an android app which is based on `supportMapFragment()` which  gets lat & lng from server in JSON format but this is not the issue for me.
My issue is I am using an android Marshmallow device(Micromax canvas A1) in this the app was running perfectly fine but after recent system update I am unable to access the app as it always Shows these exceptions:

```
Exception -  Process: com.blucursor.busapp, PID: 6099
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at com.blucursor.busapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:119)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateEx
```

after googling from more then an hour I found out some solutions suggesting to add some permissions tried all that but no success.

Comment: There should be more to that stack trace than just the stanza that you published. Successive stanzas, prefixed by "Caused by" and an exception, will help further clarify the source of your difficulty.

Comment: Problem is in your layout xml file. post here your xml file.

Comment: If there is an xml issue then why It was working fine on the older version. It stopped working only after I updated to the latest version of android and its still working in nexus 5 (marshmallow) problem is only with the Micromax canvas A1(that android one) device.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any answer?

Comment: I don't really remember how I fixed it because I tried a lot of things with it like

Comment: I don't really remember how I fixed it because I tried a lot of things with it like (1) I downgraded my update. (2) Factory reset. (3) Sim and sd card wasn't there so inserted them. (4) Added all the permissions which my App needed in the manifest file which needed according to SDK 23. you can try one of these or all of these.  P.S.:now it's working on the same. Sorry couldn't give you one precise solution. @ulusoyca

Comment: I found out that Google removed the service from our app because we by mistake violated their terms and services. Thanks anyway @VishAl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really remember how I fixed it because I tried a lot of things with it like

1. I downgraded my update.
2. Factory reset.
3. Sim and sd card wasn't there so inserted them.
4. Added all the permissions which my App needed in the manifest file which needed according to SDK 23.

One of these Done the trick for me hope it helps to someone with the same problem.

you can try one of these or all of these. 
P.S.:now it's working on the same device. 
Sorry for not being precise.

Answer (score 1):

If your app needs to access the user's location, you must request permission by adding the relevant Android location permission to your app.
For Android 6.0(API 23) and above you have to request permission runtime.
Reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#request_runtime_permissions.